# If I install Ubuntu as a dual boot, and then afterwards want to use Ubuntu as a single boot, will I lose my programs, data and files?

Tags: boot, system-installation, windows-xp

I want to retain my files, programs and data from Windows XP. I prefer to do a clean boot, but I do not want to lose my programs, files and data. Many of my programs were downloaded and I may not have the ability to download them again for free. Since Windows XP is being stopped, I do not want to setup a dual boot of Ubuntu and Windows XP. What can I do to ensure that my programs, files and data will be transferred to Ubuntu on a single boot?

Answer (score 0):

Backup all your important data in an external hard drive, or a USB stick. If you don't have a big enough external hard drive or USB stick, then gradually pass them through a USB stick to some other PC's hard drive.

Once the clean Ubuntu installation has finished, pass your data back to your PC.

This will allow you to have a clean Ubuntu installation and will leave your data untouched.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to make a backup copy. Here You may found proposition how to do it.

http://tweakhound.com/xp/backup/diskimage.htm

Save file in safe place such as cloud or USB device.
Set up Ubuntu or any Linux system of your choice and install on it for example Virtualbox. 
With Virtualbox you may create virtual machine that can operate on any OS. 
Here is some article about it

http://lifehacker.com/5204434/the-beginners-guide-to-creating-virtual-machines-with-virtualbox/all

On Virtualbox you may install regular clean installation and then you may import your backup file. You may find several difficulties that make your life hard with virtualization and your current Windows XP programs but that the way I would do it.